PDF on File System mysteriously disappeared without a trace, Windows 10
On my computer, I have a few different drives, C:/ (where my OS is stored and runs, SSD), a X:/ (Where I store my games and other things that benefit well from an SSD), and a Z:/ (HDD, for documents and such).
On my Z:, I kept an important PDF document. I had opened it last week, and a few times before that, because I needed this PDF in order to login to a website.
This morning, I opened the folder where it's saved, and the folder was empty. I figured maybe I deleted it by accident, so I checked the recycle bin. It isn't in there. So I used WonderShare RecoverIt to scan my file system for it. Nada. I downloaded another file recovery program which had the same results.
When I check "recent" in PDF X (My PDF viewer), the PDF doesn't appear either.
I figured maybe the Z: is dying, so I used the "Error checking" tool in Windows 10 to check the status of my Z:, and it comes back saying "Healthy".
When I look at the folder that the PDF was in, it says the last date modified as April 6th 7:18pm. I checked Windows event log to see if there's anything in there that would point to it being deleted, but also nothing.
I have EaseUS CleanGenius running every week, but checking the logs shows that it hasn't deleted anything off of my Z:.
I don't know what happened, where it went or what could be done. Anybody else have this happen to them? Any tips you can give?
(Apologies if this isn't the right place to post, please point me in the right direction if not)

Best bet is to restore the file from a disk image. Barring that: When you check the MRU list for your PDF viewer, does the file show in its usual location, or has it been moved? Also, try a third-party tool such as free Agent Ransack, https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/, to search all drives (including networked, if you use one) with a parameterized query, e.g., file type, size, etc. It might, or might not, be feasible to search for text inside a PDF (is the file encrypted? in image format? etc.).

Is it safe to assume that you don't already have File History configured on that drive?

@Gantendo unfortunately, the pdf is non-existent on my file system, I know the name of the pdf and I never moved it, so I don't know where it went

@Run5k yes, unfortunately I didn't have this configured..

@DrMoishePippik the file isn't shown at all in the MRU list, it's as if it has never been opened, even though I know it was opened after other items within that list. I tried using WonderShare RecoverIt already to search all drives and I don't have a networked drive.

@AustinWright, one last thought: when deleted, in some file systems, the first character of the filename might be changed -- repeat the search with wild-cards for a partial file name.

Hopefully someone else can help you recover it, but for future reference if this really is "an important PDF document," it would be prudent to store it on a drive configured for File History or better yet, OneDrive, Dropbox, or Google Drive.

Really really important files can also be copied onto a USB thumb drive for example - sure, it's not a full backup of your system that most people would recommend - but really really important files are really really important

Sometimes a disappearing file was caused for me by a false positive in the antivirus. Its vault is another place that you could check.
